# I'm trying to copy few columns from one table to another in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I am creating a Django application which has a signup and a login form. My sign up table has all the details. I want the username and password to be directly copied into the Login table. How do I write the fields for it ?

```
class Sign_up(models.Model):
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
  email_id = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  user_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
  password  = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Login(models.Model):
  log_id = models.ForeignKey(Sign_up)
  user_name = ???????????
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: Firstly, why would you do this? Secondly, **never ever ever** create your own standalone model with a password; you **must not** store passwords in plain text in your database. Django has a built-in authentication framework, you should use that; you can supply your own model but you **must** inherit from AbstractBaseUser and use the supplied functions for creating users and storing passwords.

Answer (score 0):

As a comment suggests, you should learn about database normalisation. The right question is not how to copy data from a model to another but how to 'link' models.

Therefore, I would recommend you to add a field to both models as:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

...
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Then you would need to access this field as for example:

```
Login.objects.get(pk=1).user.username
```

I would also recommend the [Django documentation: making queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/).